# Is it possible to use notarytool in macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: xcode, developer-tools, xcrun, notarization

I have to use Xcode 12.4 with macOS 10.15 Catalina for a while still for development.

**Is it possible to use `notarytool` instead of `altool`?**

I have copied `notarytool` from Xcode 13.4 Developer Tools to my `usr/local/bin` folder.
When I run in shell:

```
xcrun notarytool submit myApp.zip
```

I get this error:

> xcrun: error: unable execute utility "/usr/local/bin/notarytool"
> because it requires a newer version of macOS.

---

Without a solution, I have those 2 options:

As a last resort, I could notarize with the web API:

[Submitting software for notarization over the web](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notaryapi/submitting_software_for_notarization_over_the_web)

Or boot into my macOS 12 Monterey partition each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an easy solution:
You don't have to use `xcrun`!

With `notarytool` in `usr/local/bin` or any executable path, just use it plain like this:

```
notarytool submit myApp.zip
```

This avoids the error message and the notarization with `notarytool` with macOS 10.15 Catalina works fine.